Prove this equivalence of equations on the diff-in-diff model
I'm given this equation which corresponds to the assumption of parallel trends:
$Y_{it}^{0} = \alpha_i + \theta_t + \epsilon_{it}$
I need to prove the following diff-in-diff model specification
$y_{it}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 \alpha_i + \beta_2 \theta_t + \beta_3 \theta_t \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$
I understand how diff-in-diff works, intuition tells me $\alpha$ should kind of capture the group efect (treatment vs control group) and $\theta$ should kind of capture the time effect (pre vs post treatment period).
But I have no idea how the first simple looking equation can become this longer diff-in-diff equation. I would appreciate any help.

It cannot. There is no way you derive the second equation without a definition of $Y_{it}^1$ and an equation that relates $Y_{it}^0$ and $Y_{it}^1$ to $Y_{it}$. The latter will usually be given as $Y_{it} := D_{it}Y_{it^1} + (1-D_{it})Y_{it}^0$.

Also, you seem in your second equation to be using greek letters standardly used for unobserved fixed effects as dummy variables. Since this is non-standard notation I would advise you to be clear about how you intend your different variables to be defined.

The easiest way to motivate a regression setup from a treatment effects perspective is to assume a constant treatment effect.
In the DID setup, there are two time periods and two groups. One group is never treated. The other group is treated in period 2 only. $D_i = 1$ for treated and $D_i=0$ for non-treated.
Let the causal effect of interest be defined as the causal effect in time period $t=2$ which in counterfactual notation I define as
$$\tau_i := Y_{i2}(1) - Y_{i2}(0),$$
I assume it to be a constant
$$\forall i: \ \ \tau_i = \tau.$$
Also, I assume
\begin{align}
Y_{it}(0) &= \alpha_i + \theta_t + \epsilon_{it}, \\[8pt]
Y_{i1}(1) &= Y_{i1}(0).
\end{align}
And finally, I use the assumption that
\begin{align} 
Y_{it} &= D_iY_{it}(1) + (1-D_i)Y_{it}(0)  \\[8pt]
&=Y_{it}(0)  + D_i(Y_{it}(1) - Y_{it}(0)) \\[8pt]
&=\alpha_i + \theta_t + \tau D_i \mathbf{1}[t>1] + \epsilon_{it},
\end{align}
which should be pretty close to what you are asking for (but a little hard to know given your confusing notation - see comments).

Thanks for your answer! On the lecture notes it says in the 2x2 model $\alpha_i$ is simply $D_i$ and $\theta_i$ is simply the Post dummy. I'll see if everything checks out!

Yes, that is also what I guessed from your equation: $y_{it}=\beta_0 + \beta_1 \alpha_i + \beta_2 \theta_t + \beta_3 \theta_t \alpha_i + \epsilon_{it}$. However, this is, in my opinion, inconsistent with the equation $Y_{it}^{0} = \alpha_i + \theta_t + \epsilon_{it}$, where they are used - as I read the equation - not as dummies but rather as individual and time-specific fixed effects. But, I chose not to invest time elaborating on this since it would be guesswork in the absence of the motivating lecture note.
